# C program: Input conditon expression through file

Tags: c, file, pointers, input

I have a C code which reads parameters from an input file (Parsing word by word enabled).

I would like to input conditional expressions through the input file. For example, I should be able to use expressions like

- x

  x< 1.0

  x*x + y*y <1.0

etc., and call it in my program like:

```
    if( input_expression){
        create_points_within_geometry();
    }
```

Could someone give a crude example too?

Comment: You are basically talking about a rudimentary command interpreter. Try searching for command interpreters in C. Once you have a specific question regarding where you are stuck, post your code and we will see if we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a mathematical expression parser for C.

This code might be of help to you: https://github.com/jamesgregson/expression_parser

You can find usage examples in the author's blog: http://jamesgregson.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/mathematical-expression-parser-in-c.html